# Overwriting Builder WooCommerce Templates from Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having some issues overwriting a Builder WooCommerce (a Themify plugin that interacts with WooCommerce http://themify.me/addons/woocommerce) template from with a child theme. My child theme is set up and working, and I can successfully overwrite the WooCommerce product page images from (childTheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php). That all works great, but when I try and overwrite a template within the Builder WooCommerce Plugin (product listing template) nothing seems to happen.

I've copied the appropriate template file into (childTheme/builder-woocommerce/template-products-list.php) and made modifications, but they are not coming through at all. Is it for some reason why overriding this plugin doesn't work?

Comment: Is your parent theme filtering `woocommerce_template_path`?

Comment: yes it's because of `builder-woocommerce`... try it with `woocommerce` folder to confirm...

Comment: helgatheviking, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. There is no reference to 'woocommerce_template_path' in any folder but the woocommerce plugin folder. Defininitely not in the parent theme. Reigel, I'm going to try that, but in the plugins folder they are separated that way, 'woocommerce' being separate from 'builder-woocommerce', and the respective files in the correct places. I doubt this will solve it, as the file is meant to be in builder-woocommerce.

Comment: Reigel, confirmed, this did not solve it.

Comment: So your theme has both a `woocommerce` folder and a `builder-woocommerce` folder? In that case, it depends on your theme to make it possible to use template overrides in other folders. WordPress will default to template overrides on core templates in theme folder root (`index.php` and the like) as well as templates called via `get_template_part()`. And WooCommerce has it's own template override system enabled. But I have no idea how your theme behaves. You are probably best served by contacting the theme author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Themify support, and was told:

> Child theme can only save theme files. Builder woocommerce is a addon/plugin. It is not possible to save plugin files through child theme. You can copy customized files manually and replace it with the updated file after plugin update.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to make changes to any template file within this plugin from a child theme.